# numerical methods to solve the double integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

How is this integral solve numerically over the region $D= \left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2} : 0\leq x \leq 7.5; 0\leq y \leq 8  \right \}$. I mean is it done like with the analytical expression, first is done for $x$ and then $y$?

$$\iint_{D}^{} \frac{ \mathrm dx \,\mathrm dy}{(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

I was also thinking like use spherical coordinates, like $f(x,y,z) \rightarrow f(\rho \cos \theta \sin \phi,\rho  \sin \theta \sin\phi, \rho \cos \phi )$ but not so sure, since the $z$ is not part of the integrand.

Comment: You have to use brute force, as the region of integration doesn't obey any kind of symmetry.

Comment: @LasDes What do you know about $z$? Can you rule out the case  $z=0$?

Comment: The case of $z=0$ is rules out but, in the pure sense of the thinking in the result, maybe $z$ can be treated like a given parameter or a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z \ne 0$, the integrand is smooth over the integration region and you can apply a quadrature rule of your choice (e.g. the trapezoidal rule). It would be generically something like
$$
I \approx \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m \omega_{ij} f(x_i,x_j)
$$

Or you can compute the integral analytically (say $z>0$)

$$
I = \frac{1}{z} \arctan\left( \frac{960}{z \sqrt{481+4z^2}}\right).
$$